# Show that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $f'(x)\to f'(c)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x \in (a,b)$. Let $c \in (a,b)$, show that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $(a,b)$ with $x_n \neq c$ and $x_n \to c$ such that $f'(x_n) \to f'(c)$

This is a question and I need to use the Mean value theorem for proving it.

In addition, does $f'(x_n) \to f'(c)$ for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n \to c$?

Comment: This sounds like an IVP problem

Comment: Maybe I'm just not educated enough, but I don't understand the notation you've used. Do you mean $x_n \rightarrow c$ or $\exists x : f(x)=c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\lambda>0$ so that $c+\lambda<b$. Then the mean value theorem ensures an $x_n\in(c,c+\lambda/n)$ such that
$$
f^\prime(x_n)=\frac{f(c+\lambda/n)-f(c)}{\lambda/n}
$$
It follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f^\prime(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(c+\lambda/n)-f(c)}{\lambda/n}\overset{\ast}{=}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}\overset{\circledast}{=}f^\prime(c)
$$
where $\ast$ follows by taking $h=\lambda/n$ and $\circledast$ follows from the definition of the derivative.
Hence $x_n\to c$ and $f^\prime(x_n)\to f^\prime(c)$.

It is not necessarily true that $f^\prime(x_n)\to f^\prime(c)$ whenever $x_n\to c$. Indeed, if $f^\prime$ is not continuous at $c$, then by definition there exists $x_n\to c$ such that $f^\prime(x_n)\not\to f^\prime(c)$. Can you find a particular $f(x)$ that gives your counterexample?

Comment: how about f(x)=0 for x=0 and x^2*sin(1/x) for otherwise as a counterexample?

Comment: @user155900 yes that would work